# Random Number Generation within a range

Tags: java, random

I am trying to print a random number between 80 and 100.
However when I print out this number I am getting numbers over 100?

```
Random num = new Random();
int percent = 80 + num.nextInt(100);
System.out.println(percent);
```

Comment: The output for example is 154 etc.

Comment: `Random.nextInt(100)` will produce a random number between 0 and 99. You want to do `80 + num.nextInt(20)`.

Comment: Below , Me and @Zabuza  answered  , it will  help you ,

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try something like this**

There are two approach below

```
int resultNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(80, 100 + 1);
System.out.println(resultNumber);
```

```
Random num = new Random();
int min =80;
int max=100;
System.out.println(num.nextInt(max-min) + min);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

From the documentation of [Random#nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between `0` (inclusive) and the **specified value** (exclusive), [...]

So your call

```
num.nextInt(100);
```

Generates numbers between `0` (inclusive) and `100` (exclusive). After that you add `80` to it. The resulting range for your `percent` is thus `80` (inclusive) to `180` (exclusive).

---

### Solution

In order to get a number from `80` to `100`, what you actually want to do is to generate a number from `0` to `20` and add that on top of `80`. So

```
int percent = 80 + num.nextInt(20);
```

The general formula is

```
int result = lowerBound + random.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound);
```

---

### Notes

Favor using `ThreadLocalRandom` over `new Random()`, it is faster because it sacrifices thread-safety (which you most likely do not need). So:

```
Random num = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
```

It actually also has an additional `nextInt(int, int)` method for exactly this use case. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int)):

> Returns a pseudorandom int value between the **specified origin** (inclusive) and the **specified bound** (exclusive).

The code would then just be:

```
int percent = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(80, 100);
```

All my examples so far assumed that `100` is **exclusive**. If you want it to be **inclusive**, just add `1` to it. So for example

```
int percent = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(80, 101);
```

Comment: Good explanation dear